# Unable to Connect to SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, soap, xml

I'm unable to connect to a freestanding instance of marketing cloud via API using XML. Getting 'invalid username, password, security token or locked out' error. the username, password and account are good, however I see no way to acquire the security token. We've reset passwords, created new users and no luck. The client does not have support services that include API, so no help there. Is the Security only applicable for accounts integrated with sales/service cloud? is there another way to connect with XML?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of Marketing cloud but check the profile and see if you have any IP login ranges present. If yes, then you do not need a security token to login to salesforce and it won't be available under `your name->My Settings->security token` where it usually is when IP ranges are not set.
[image]

Comment: There are no IP login ranges, and the MC dashboard does not have the string a my settings > security token. i've scoured the user profiles and admin tabs, nothing about a token. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

**Common pitfalls when connecting to the SOAP-API are:**

- You are using the wrong endpoint, that isn't the one for your instance/stack.
- Your user doesn't have the "API User" property enabled

**Further information:**

- [Work with the SOAP API (includes all the endpoints)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/working_with_soap_web_service_api.htm)

Comment: We're using the correct endpoint and stack- is this an account enablement issue?